# Rails 3 virtual attributes used in another Models controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, virtual-attribute

Experimenting an issue trying to achieve a virtual attributes of a model in another controller.
 Is there a way to do it?

Here is the virtual attributes:

```
def montant
  self.facture_details.sum(:montant_detail)
end

def paiements
  self.facture_paiements.sum(:montant)
end

def facture_statut
  if self.paiements < self.montant
  then
    "Ouverte"
  else
    "Payée"
  end
end
```

And in another controller I'm trying to do:

```
 @factures = Facture.find(:all, :conditions => {:facture_statut => 'Ouverte'})
```

When I do this I got an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: factures.facture_statut: SELECT "factures".* FROM "factures" WHERE "factures"."facture_statut" = 'Ouverte'
```

Is there someone to help me with this?

Thanks

Update; here is the full model:

```
class Facture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facture_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :facture_paiements
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :facture_details, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :facture_paiements
  attr_accessor :facture_statut
  attr_accessor :montant
  attr_accessor  :paiements
  def montant
    self.facture_details.sum(:montant_detail)
  end
  def paiements
    self.facture_paiements.sum(:montant)
  end
  def facture_statut
    if self.paiements < self.montant
      then
      "Ouverte"
    else
      "Payée"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have `facture_statut` declared in the model as `attr_accessible`; e.g. `attr_accessible :facture_statut?

Comment: Still getting: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: factures.facture_statut: SELECT "factures".* FROM "factures" WHERE "factures"."facture_statut" = 'Ouverte'

Comment: Can you post your whole model?

Comment: Here it is. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Okay... after digging into it, it looks like you cannot do what you want using the find method, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894337/ruby-on-rails-virtual-attributes-in-conditions). Sergio usually knows what he is talking about. However one of the other responders, Benjamin, and the answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806394/rails-virtual-attribute-search-or-sql-combined-column-search) offer a different approach that should work; using a scope.

So rather than this:

```
@factures = Facture.find(:all, :conditions => {:facture_statut => 'Ouverte'})
```

You would need to add a scope to the model and then call the scope:

```
class Facture < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :facture_statut lambda {|facture_statut| {:facture_statut => facture_statut}}
  #rest of class
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
Fracture.facture_statut('Ouverte')
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've tried your solution that sounds highly promising and get an error:
Unknown key(s): facture_statut
Any idea about the problem?